# Creating a list of times using a for loop

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop

I have written a very simple code that takes the current datetime and assigns it to a variable. What I am trying to accomplish is create a list of 6 datetimes at 5 minute intervals 30 minute before the current datetime. I am almost certain I can do this in a loop instead of the current hardcoded method I am using. Any tips from the pros here?

```
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
timethen = timenow - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

#Make this list a loop somehow. Ask stack community..

t1=timethen+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
t2=t1+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
t3=t2+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
t4=t3+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
t5=t4+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
t6=t5+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
timelist = [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6]

print(timenow)
print(timethen)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty trivial with a for loop:

```py
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
timethen = timenow - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

#Make this list a loop somehow. Ask stack community..
timelist = []
for i in range(1, 7):
  timelist.append(timethen+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5*i))

print(timenow)
print(timethen)
```

This basically does the same thing as your code above, appending timedeltas in 5 minute increments.

Comment: To make the list a loop: `timelist = [timethen + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5 * i) for i in range(1,7)]`

Comment: Clarification: Henry's solution is called list comprehension.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: @ericl16384 Thanks, I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

From what I can tell you want to make a list of 5 min intervals from `timenow` to `timethen`:

```py
timelist = pd.date_range(timethen, timenow, freq='5min')
```